# smooth morphisms and sheaf of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-varieties, local-rings

Our course defined a smooth morphism in this way

[image: our]

I'd like to know why this implies that the sheaf of differentials $\Omega_{X/S}^1$ is locally free of finite rank. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried/where have you looked for references? This is pretty straightforwards - the question is local on $X$ and $S$, so one can pick $X$ and $S$ to be affine, write the map on rings in a particularly nice fashion, and compute.